# Set origin and rotation on animateMotion's path

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'd like to apply a rotation on a path animated with SVG's animateMotion tag. 
It seems that the rule *transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(240deg);* applied on the path that the animateMotion tag follows doesn't alter the animation.

```
<path id="theMotionPathIdLikeToRotate" d="m 100,100 -3e-6,-52.916668 45.82718,26.458333 0,52.916665" stroke-width="5px" stroke="aqua" fill="none" style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(120deg);" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
```

My aim was to create an animation and repeat it transformed. [In this example](https://jsfiddle.net/fillotassi/by3Lxf0h/6/)  I wanted to create other moving circles, rotated 120 and 240 degrees around the center of the hexagon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the path definition (`d`) of the path referenced by an `<mpath>` element is used.  Any `transform` it might have is ignored.

You would need to apply the transform to the circle and the `<mpath>` together.

```
    <g style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(240deg);">
      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
        <animateMotion dur="4.45s" repeatCount="once">
          <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath3"/>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
    </g>"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <body>
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background:aquamarine">
        <style>
        path {
          animation-name:animateDash;
          animation-duration:5s;
          animation-iteration-count:once;
        }
        @keyframes animateDash {
          from{stroke-dasharray:0,2305}
          to  {stroke-dasharray:2305,0}
        }
        </style>


        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="1" fill="firebrick"  />

        <path id="theMotionPath" d="m 100,100 -3e-6,-52.916668 45.82718,26.458333 0,52.916665" stroke-width="5px" stroke="antiquewhite" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />

        <path id="theMotionPath2" d="m 100,100 -3e-6,-52.916668 45.82718,26.458333 0,52.916665" stroke-width="5px" stroke="aqua" fill="none" style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(120deg);" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        
        <path id="theMotionPath3" d="m 100,100 -3e-6,-52.916668 45.82718,26.458333 0,52.916665" stroke-width="5px" stroke="azure" fill="none" style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(240deg);" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />

        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
          <animateMotion dur="4.45s" repeatCount="once">
            <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath3"/>
          </animateMotion>
        </circle>

        <g style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(120deg);">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
            <animateMotion dur="4.45s" repeatCount="once">
              <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath3"/>
            </animateMotion>
          </circle>
        </g>"

        <g style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(240deg);">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
            <animateMotion dur="4.45s" repeatCount="once">
              <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath3"/>
            </animateMotion>
          </circle>
        </g>"

    <!--- HIDES animateMotion's reset-->
            <circle cx="" cy="" r="20" fill="aquamarine"  />
      <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(theMotionPath.getTotalLength());
      </script>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```